# Kafka Connect Date type should not have any time fields set to non-zero values

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb

I am creating a kafka source connector with KSQL.
The MariaDb connector fails to read data from mariadb when the date field is populated with values like '2020-09-30' (the type of this column in the db table is Date).

I get this error on the kafka connect log

```
Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:187)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:196)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:122)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.convertTransformedRecord(WorkerSourceTask.java:314)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:340)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:235)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Kafka Connect Date type should not have any time fields set to non-zero values.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Date.fromLogical(Date.java:64)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData$6.convert(AvroData.java:282)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.fromConnectData(AvroData.java:394)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.fromConnectData(AvroData.java:581)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.fromConnectData(AvroData.java:340)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.fromConnectData(AvroConverter.java:87)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.fromConnectData(Converter.java:63)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.lambda$convertTransformedRecord$2(WorkerSourceTask.java:314)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:180)
```

When I look at the generated Avro schema it seems to be having the correct data type

```
{\"name\":\"enrollment_date\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"int\",\"connect.version\":1,\"connect.name\":\"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Date\",\"logicalType\":\"date\"}],\"default\":null}
```

Not really sure why this happens and how to fix it.
There are two github links about similar issue but no clear fix is mentioned.
I am using confluent platform version 6.0.0

Update: Using the Mysql connector Jar instead of MariaDb made this work. Same table/data and no more errors after switching the connector. All rows are present in the auto generated topic. So this issue should be related to the MariaDB connector.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the conversion between Date from DB and the final state of the record could be implicit inject a timezone different from UTC. probably your jdk its in other timezone or in some custom conversion you should force UTC.